# how to draw pixels to pf1bit in Delphi?

Tags: image, delphi

How to draw pixels to a TImage but in pf1bit bitmap format? I have tried but the result is **the whole of the image are black**.

here is the code I've tried :

```
image1.picture.bitmap.loadfromfile('example.bmp'); // an image which is RGB pf24bit with 320 x 240 px resolution
image1.picture.bitmap.pixelformat := pf1bit;
for i:=0 to round(image1.picture.bitmap.canvas.height/2) - 1 do
  begin
    for j:=0 to round(image1.picture.bitmap.canvas.width/2) - 1 do
      begin
        image1.picture.bitmap.Canvas.pixels[i,j]:=1; // is this correct? ... := 1? I've tried to set it to 255 (mean white), but still get black 
      end;
  end;
```

note that the image size is 320x240 pixel.

Thanks before.

Comment: Not an answer, but FWIW, instead of `Round(x/2)`, you better do `x div 2`. And you can use `image1.height` directly.

Comment: image1.height is different with image1.picture.bitmap.height, image1.height is TImage size, but image1.picture.bitmap.height is the real image size (image inside TImage) :D

Comment: You still need to use bitwise operations like I said in a comment to the question that you deleted.

Comment: Leftmost pixel is in msb. Once you know that then it's pretty easy. Use of shl 1 and then writing a byte to scanline each time you complete  8 bits. Remember that you have to pack 8 pixels into a single byte.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yeah, thanks for ur answer for the question that I've deleted before :D , would u mind tell me sample pseudocode? I don't really understand. :D oh ya do u have YM (Yahoo ID)? may be we could chat :D

Comment: @user1210396 you can chat directly on the site.

Comment: @Blobby: yeah but I'm new here still need to get reputation to allow chat :D

Comment: @user1210396: OK, `image1.height` is indeed the height of the `TImage`, and that may be different. Then use `image1.picture.height`. But using `round()` is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I do not mean to argue which is better, just would like to point out that `Round(x/2)` is not the same as `x div 2`. (But `Trunc(x/2)` is.)

Comment: @AndriyM: nice share :D thanks

Comment: @Andriy: I know, but div 2 is the usual way to do this. Dividing by 2 using `/` to get an Extended result and than rounding again is *extremely* slow compared to `div 2`. The difference is, at most, one pixel.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Makes sense absolutely. And if they wanted the result to be exactly the same, they could just do `(x + 1) div 2`, couldn't they.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pack 8 pixels into a single byte for 1 bit color format. The inner loop would look like this:

```
var
  bm: TBitmap;
  i, j: Integer;
  dest: ^Byte;
  b: Byte;
  bitsSet: Integer;
begin
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  Try
    bm.PixelFormat := pf1bit;
    bm.SetSize(63, 30);
    for i := 0 to bm.Height-1 do begin
      b := 0;
      bitsSet := 0;
      dest := bm.Scanline[i];
      for j := 0 to bm.Width-1 do begin
        b := b shl 1;
        if odd(i+j) then
          b := b or 1;
        inc(bitsSet);
        if bitsSet=8 then begin
          dest^ := b;
          inc(dest);
          b := 0;
          bitsSet := 0;
        end;
      end;
      if b<>0 then
        dest^ := b shl (8-bitsSet);
    end;
    bm.SaveToFile('c:\desktop\out.bmp');
  Finally
    bm.Free;
  End;
end;
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

**Update**

Rob's comment prompted me to look at using `Pixels[]` rather than the bit-twiddling above. And indeed it is perfectly possible.

```
var
  bm: TBitmap;
  i, j: Integer;
  Color: TColor;
begin
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  Try
    bm.PixelFormat := pf1bit;
    bm.SetSize(63, 30);
    for i := 0 to bm.Height-1 do begin
      for j := 0 to bm.Width-1 do begin
        if odd(i+j) then begin
          Color := clBlack;
        end else begin
          Color := clWhite;
        end;
        bm.Canvas.Pixels[j,i] := Color;
      end;
    end;
    bm.SaveToFile('c:\desktop\out.bmp');
  Finally
    bm.Free;
  End;
end;
```

Since each call to assign `Pixels[]` results in a call to the Windows API function `SetPixel`, the bit-twiddling code would perform better. Of course, that would only ever matter if your bitmap creation code was a performance hot-spot.

Comment: Is this to say that use of the `Pixels` property as shown in the question doesn't work for 1 bpp images?

Comment: @RobKennedy You are right on the money as usual. I assumed (erroneously) that `Pixels[]` was no good with 1bpp images. That assumption was wrong.